# Can blender game engine hide vertices that are not visible to the camera?

Tags: game-engine, optimization

Is it possible for the Blender Game Engine to hide any vertices/faces currently not visible to the camera in order to optimize game performance? This would be for parts of meshes specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. This is done by using the `Occlude` physics type; this makes an object hide all other objects (or parts of objects) behind it. This does, however, mean that it can only be applied to *Static* (physics type) objects, since an object can't have two physics types, and the Occlude type works like the Static type (i.e. it doesn't move).

Keep in mind that:

> - If the occluders are small and don't hide many objects.
>
>   - In that case, occlusion culling is just dragging your CPU down).
> - If the occluders are large but hides simple objects.
>
>   - In that case you're better off sending the objects to the GPU).

You can [read the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Physics/Object/Occluder) for more details [about performance](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Physics/Object/Occluder#Recommendations).

Answer (score 1):

To build on @someonewithpc 's answer;

This is generally used to set up **render zones** where static doors or walls with occlude enabled hide rooms with complex geometry.

Another way is to parent an occlude to the back of the head of you character;
This will hide pretty much everything you can't see.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the second way, which involves parenting an occluding object to the character?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote this answer a while ago and more extensive testing shows that the second way does not work. :-(